# Docker container - How to inspect destination structure before running the container?

Tags: macos, docker

I am running a docker container with my local home folder on my Mac with the following code:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v ~:/home/jovyan/workspace jupyter/all-spark-notebook
```

It works this way, however my question is, how would I know the structure of the destination, which is /home/jovyan/workspace. I would like to mount it as

```
-v ~:/folder_name
```

However this way, my folder doesn't appear in jupyter notebook as the container already runs with the directory set to workspace.

How can I mount my local folder without running an exec command and manually inspecting the destination folder structure, so that my folder appears in the set directory? Will appreciate any comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to run it this way:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v ~:/folder_name -w /folder_name <imagename>
```

This way, -w sets the directory to the folder *folder_name* I specify in the container.

Answer (score 0):

you can almost always just run `docker run -it containername sh` and use it as an shell environment, `sh` is hereby your command, which overrides `CMD` in your container and executes, some container come with `ash` or even `bash` support

Comment: This is also good knowledge thank you! My real question was how to override the default directory of the container. I finally figured out and posted below.